# gzip already has gz suffix unchanged in the script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, gzip

I have created a script to zip and move log files from one directory to another directory to free space. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

logsDirectory="/test//logs/" 
email="" 
backupDirectory="/test/backup" 
pid="/data/test/scripts/backup.pid"
usage=$(df | grep /data/logs | awk '{ print $2 }') 
space=450000000

getBackup () 
{ 
if [[ ! -e $pid ]] then
            if [[ $usage -le $space ]]
                    then
                    touch $pid
                    find $backupDirectory -mtime +15 -type f  -delete;
                    for i in $(find $logsDirectory -type f -not -path "*/irws/*")
                            do
                                    /sbin/fuser $i > /dev/null 2>&1
                                    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                                    then
                                            gzip  $i
                                            mv -v $i.gz $backupDirectory
                                    else
                                            continue
                                    fi
                            done
                    [[ ! -z $email ]] && echo "Backup is ready" | mas"Backup" $email
                    rm -f $pid
            fi 
fi 
} 
getBackup
```

I am getting this error:

```
gzip: /data/logs/log01.log.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged
mv: cannot stat `/data/logs/log01.log.gz': No such file or directory
```

I got the error every time I ran the script in my DEV and PROD (CentOS servers) environments. To analyse it, I ran the same script in a VM (Ubuntu) in my laptop, and I don't get the error there.

My questions:

1. How can I prevent this error?
2. What I have done wrong in the script?

Comment: The file `/data/logs/log01.log.gz` exists in `$logsDirectory`. `gzip` tells you that the file already has the `.gz` extension and won't compress it again. Then you try to move `/data/logs/log01.log.gz.gz` into the backup directory. That fails. Also, consider running your script with `set -x`.

Comment: Just add a step to test, and if it already ends in .gz, just skip it, or move it.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, they helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script contains a number of common clumsy or inefficient antipatterns.  Here is a refactoring.  The only real change is skipping any `*.gz` files.

```
#!/bin/bash

logsDirectory="/test//logs/" 
email="" 
backupDirectory="/test/backup" 
pid="/data/test/scripts/backup.pid"
# Avoid useless use of grep -- awk knows how to match a regex
# Better still run df /data/logs
usage=$(df /data/logs/ | awk '{ print $2 }') 
space=450000000

getBackup () 
{
    # Quote variables
    if [[ ! -e "$pid" ]]; then
        if [[ "$usage" -le "$space" ]]; then
            touch "$pid"
            find "$backupDirectory" -mtime +15 -type f  -delete;
            # Exclude *.gz files
            # This is still not robust against file names with spaces or wildcards in their names
            for i in $(find "$logsDirectory" -type f -not -path "*/irws/*" -not -name '*.gz')
            do
                # Avoid useless use of $?
                if /sbin/fuser "$i" > /dev/null 2>&1
                then
                        gzip  "$i"
                        mv -v "$i.gz" "$backupDirectory"
                # no need for do-nothing else
                fi
            done
            [[ ! -z "$email" ]] &&
            echo "Backup is ready" | mas"Backup" "$email"
            rm -f "$pid"
        fi
    fi
}
getBackup
```

With a slightly more intrusive refactoring, the proper fix to the `find` loop would perhaps look something like

```
            find "$logsDirectory" -type f \
              -not -path "*/irws/*" -not -name '*.gz' \
              -exec sh -c '
                for i; do
                    if /sbin/fuser "$i" > /dev/null 2>&1
                    then
                        gzip  "$i"
                        mv -v "$i.gz" "$backupDirectory"
                    fi
                done' _ {} +
```

where the secret sauce is to have `find ... -exec +` pass in the arguments to the `sh -c` script in a way which does not involve exposing the arguments to the current shell at all.

Comment: Thank you for you awesome solution, it worked perfectly, am still a newbie in bash scripting. May the force be with you.

Answer (score 0):

> What I have done wrong in the script?

Your script tries to zip every file but the `gzip` command is rejecting files already zipped

> How can I prevent this error?

Have the script check whether the file is zipped or not and only gzip if it corresponds (1). Alternatively, you could force re-compression even if it is already compressed (2).

Going with option number 1):

```
getBackup () 
{ 
  if [[ ! -e $pid ]] then
    if [[ $usage -le $space ]]
    then
      touch $pid
      find $backupDirectory -mtime +15 -type f  -delete;
      for i in $(find $logsDirectory -type f -not -path "*/irws/*")
      do
        /sbin/fuser $i > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
          if [[ $i =~ \.gz$ ]]
            # File is already zipped
            mv -v $i $backupDirectory
          else
            gzip  $i
            mv -v $i.gz $backupDirectory
          fi
        else
          continue
        fi
      done
      [[ ! -z $email ]] && echo "Backup is ready" | mas"Backup" $email
      rm -f $pid
    fi 
  fi 
}
```